# DayZ standalone resolution help!

Tags: dayz-standalone

I have downloaded the DayZ standalone game from within steam!! I need help, as when i open the game, the resolution only goes up to a certain amount and this is absolutely tiny on my screen! Is there a way i can manually enter the resolution of my screen in some of the files?? Thanks very much!

Comment: Documents/DayZ/Day.cfg

Comment: I would say you have to select your screen  aspect ratio first with another option (16:9, 4:3 etc.) then the resolution appropriate to your screen will be available. But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Do not use the `Overall Quality`-Preset the developers made. Be sure to set "Render resolution" to 100% or higher. Your game will look blurry if you set it smaller than 100%

Answer (score 1):

Try to select your screen aspect ratio first with another option (like `16:9` or `4:3`) then the resolution to your screen should be available. If you want to manually change your screen resolution, you can change it in the `Day.cfg` file found in `Documents/Dayz`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the resolution that's the problem and not your interface size? There's an "Interface size" setting in the options. See circled setting in the attached picture.

[image: DayZ Interface size setting]

Comment: Thoose are the settings of the DayZ Mod for Arma II. He asks for the graphic settings of the Standalone edition

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to delete (AFTER a backup copy) the **Day.cfg** file found in Documents/Dayz.

I had similiar issue LOT of times. I suppose that sometime the cfg save a wrong interface resolution. After deleting MANY times the Day.cfg time I have found a working configuration and never touched again both **render and inteface** resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the `Overall Quality`-Preset the developers made. That function doesn't work on my computer either. You have to set the settings manually ingame or via the DayZ.cfg.

Be sure to set "Render resolution" to 100% or higher. Your game will look blurry if you set it smaller than 100%
You'll supersample when you put the value higher than 100% which can also increase your graphic quality.

[image: How my DayZ looks like]

You see how my game looks like. [Here's my DayZ.cfg](http://pastebin.com/5Xisjw0L). Please make sure that you insert your screen resolution at `Resolution_W`, `Resolution_H`, `Render_W` and `Render_H`

Here are my settings how I set them ingame:

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5YDE.jpg)

- [User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cs3g.jpg)
- [Textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUw8.jpg) <sub>I set Memory to 2048 (not on the image)</sub>
- [Quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nLSg.jpg)
- [Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBr1c.jpg)

I have postprocessing enabled, but you can disable it. Many people don't like the post processing of DayZ. Also, you can turn up your brightness to see better at night

Comment: I sure dont know why I got -1 voting. He says that his graphic settings do not work thats why i showed him mine. I did also explained everything. Some other guy who commented here talked about the DayZ Mod. thats a completely diffrent game.